# Polymer local dom

Tags: javascript, polymer

I played around with Polymer's local dom selector `$$`. I want to know if an element with a certain attribute exists. I wrote below example.

Is it by intention, that I cannot reach elements within other custom elements with the `$$` selector? 
How can I check for the existence of elements inside anothers element?
Is it good to go with `document.querySelector`?

```html
<script src="https://elements.polymer-project.org/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.0.1/lib/polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="my-moduleone">
    <style>
        :host {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            display: block;
        }        
    </style>
    <template>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <content select="*" /> 
        </div>
        Counter 1: <span counter1>0</span>
        <input type="button" value="Increment counter" on-click="_incrementCounter"/>
    </template>
    <script>
        (function () {
      Polymer({
        is: 'my-moduleone',
        _incrementCounter: function() {
            this.$$('[counter1]').innerHTML++;
            this.querySelector('[counter2]').innerHTML++;
            this.$$('[counter3]').innerHTML++;
        }
      });
    })();
    </script>
</dom-module>
<dom-module id="my-moduletwo">
    <style>
        :host {
            width: 100%;
            display: inline-block;
        } 
        .counter {
            float: left;
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            display: block;
        }
        .blue {
            background-color: lightblue;
        }
        .magenta {
            background-color: magenta;
        }
    </style>
    <template>
        <content select="*" />
        <span class="counter blue">
        Counter 2: <span counter2>0</span>
        </span>
        <span class="counter magenta">
        Counter 3: <span counter3>0</span>
        </span>
    </template>
    <script>
        (function () {
      Polymer({
        is: 'my-moduletwo'
      });
    })();
    </script>
</dom-module>
<my-moduleone>
  <my-moduletwo>
  </my-moduletwo>
</my-moduleone>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've said it yourself: `this.$$` is a **local dom** selector. That means you cannot access elements that are added in the light dom. If you are going to access elements in the light dom (or access elements that aren't added in the local dom at registration time), use `Polymer.dom` instead. This is Polymer's suggested way of manipulating elements, be it in the light dom or the local dom. You also should not use `document.querySelector` in accessing elements that are inside the local dom of the element since this method cannot (by default) access the shadow dom.

Here is an example of using `Polymer.dom`:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <base href="http://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
</head>

<body>
  <dom-module id="my-component-one">
    <template>
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <content select="*" />
      </div>
      Counter 1: <span counter1>0</span>
      <input type="button" value="Increment counter" on-click="_incrementCounter" />
    </template>
  </dom-module>
  <dom-module id="my-component-two">
    <template>
      <content select="*" />
      <span class="counter blue">
          Counter 2: <span counter2>0</span>
      </span>
      <span class="counter magenta">
          Counter 3: <span counter3>0</span>
      </span>
    </template>
  </dom-module>

  <my-component-one>
    <my-component-two></my-component-two>
  </my-component-one>

  <script>
    (function() {
      Polymer({
        is: 'my-component-one',
        _incrementCounter: function() {
          // Note: Polymer.dom(this) accesses the light dom. Use Polymer.dom(this.root) 
          // to access the element's local dom
          var componentTwo = Polymer.dom(this).querySelector('my-component-two');

          if (!componentTwo) return; // don't do anything when there is no my-component-two

          // access element's local dom by getting it's root property
          var c2_counter2 = Polymer.dom(componentTwo.root).querySelector('[counter2]');
          var c2_counter3 = Polymer.dom(componentTwo.root).querySelector('[counter3]');
          var c1_counter1 = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('[counter1]'); // this can be shortened to this.$$
          var c1c1 = parseInt(c1_counter1.innerHTML);
          var c2c2 = parseInt(c2_counter2.innerHTML);
          var c2c3 = parseInt(c2_counter3.innerHTML);
          c1_counter1.innerHTML = c1c1 + 1;
          c2_counter2.innerHTML = c2c2 + 1;
          c2_counter3.innerHTML = c2c3 + 1;
        }
      });
      Polymer({
        is: 'my-component-two'
      });
    })();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```